# Lines from webpage to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, url, html

I have used python for several different things, but I have never worked with webpages before so I am not exactly sure what to do. Basically I have a webpage where I want to find key words and then write the line that contains that key word to a dictionary. I really have no idea how to go about this. This is what I have so far. Any kind of guidance would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import sys, re
import csv
import pylab as pl
import math
import argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib

link = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf-c78D25Vd52Na0yx1bWjniINPuGmhx2kM3Nr3VNsMYmIpRQ/viewform?usp=sf_link'

r = requests.get(link)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

quiz = {}

tmp = soup.findAll('Short Answer', 'Fill in the Blank', 'Multiple Choice', 'Matching', 'Numeric Response')

for i in tmp:
    print(i.get_text())
```

Comment: Search the html for useful tags, select with bs4 and add to dictionary.

Comment: What you read is a html not file so use beautifulsoup with re to get better results

Comment: I have tried using soup.findall, but I am not sure what all I can do with this. I want it to be able to find any of the key words I have and then add the whole sentence to a dictionary. In the style dict[key word] = sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentences are embedded in `javascript` within the `html`, so get the javascript text first, then use python's Regular Expression module, [re](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), in a loop to find each keyword one at a time:

```
quiz = {}

terms = ['Short Answer', 'Fill in the Blank', 'Multiple Choice', 'Matching', 'Numeric Response']

# get the javascript content
text = soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript")[1].string

# loop through the terms searching the javascript text and get the entire sentence
for term in terms:
    # Use RegEx to get the complete sentence between double quotes
    line = re.findall(r"([\"]*?" + term + "[^\"]*\")", text)
    quiz[term] = line # assign the sentence to the quiz entry
```

Then you can access each sentence in the form `dict[keyword] = sentence`:

```
print(quiz['Multiple Choice']) # [u'"Multiple Choice: In which of the following no information hiding is done ?"']
```

note the empty entries:

```
print(quiz['Numeric Response']) # []
```

Hope this helps.